# Cannot cast to an Extended Class in Java

Tags: java, android, casting, extends

I looked around for a similar issue but couldn't find anything that matched it.

I'm trying to extend the built-in JSONObject to add some functionality, like so:

```
public class MyJSONObject extends JSONObject {

    // Easily return an integer from a JSONObject, handling when the value is null.
    //
    public Integer getIntegerUnlessNull(String key) throws JSONException {
        String key_value = this.getString (key);

        if ( key_value.equals("null") ) {
            return null;

        } else {
            return Integer.parseInt( key_value );
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to cast it, I get a `java.lang.ClassCastException` error:

```
private JSONArray    jsonClients;
        MyJSONObject clientJSONRecord;

clientJSONRecord = (MyJSONObject) jsonClients.getJSONObject(0);
```

The full error message is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to com.insightemissions.trak.extensions.MyJSONObject
```

Any help?

Cheers,

JP

Comment: Please post your json which you trying to parse....

Comment: If the source is not real instance of MyJSONObject, it is not possible to cast.

Comment: The JSONObject comes from this library: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject()

Comment: @HarshitRathi I don't think the actual JSON matters in this case. If I simply remove the casting, the code works fine. I'm simply trying to add some additional functionality to keep the code DRY.

Comment: @Nambari Can you explain a bit more. The `getJSONObject(index)` methods results in a JSONObject instance.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html may help you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`jsonClients.getJSONObject(0)` returns an object of the type `JSONObject` which is your parent type.

You cannot cast it to the inherited type. It only works the other way, i.e. casting an inherited class to a parent class. This has nothing to do with your objects in particular, it just the way inheritance works.

Because you get an instance of `JSONObject` from the method and you cannot control how it's instantiated, you could add a constructor to your `MyJSONObject` class to create an object from the parent object:

```
public MyJSONObject(JSONObject parent) {
    super(parent.toString());
}
```

And use it this way:

```
JSONObject parent = jsonClients.getJSONObject(0);
MyJSONObject child = new MyJSONObject(parent);
```

Comment: You're correct, that's what it returns. How do I go about turning it into a MyJSONObject to unlock the additional functionality?

Comment: Hmm... okay, making more sense, except why the `parent.toString()`?

Comment: I think that's a JSONObject constructor that will be easiest to use.

Comment: That constructor doesn't exist. How would I go about constructing a JSONObject from an existing JSONObject?

Comment: It is in the documentation though... I used the link you provided.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Worked like a charm. just had to fix a missing colon in your reply. Nice work Szymon, thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42624/discussion-between-josh-pinter-and-szymon)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that the objects inside the `JSONArray`  (I presume the `JSONArray` object is created by the library) do not contain `MyJSONObject` objects that are defined by you.

Your code would work only if you created the `JSONArray` yourself and populated it with `MyJSONObject` objects.

Given what you are trying to achieve with this "extended functionality", I think inheritance is much of an overkill.

Why not just use a helper method?

```
public Integer getIntegerUnlessNull(JSONObject, String key) throws JSONException {
    String key_value = object.getString (key);

    if ( key_value.equals("null") ) {
        return null;

    } else {
        return Integer.parseInt( key_value );
    }
}
```

Then you can just do this:

```
Integer getInteger = getIntegerUnlessNull(object, "key");
if (getInteger == null) {
    // if null do something
}
```

Comment: In this particular case, you're probably right with going with the helper class, however, I'm keen to find out how to extend it with more functionality in case I need to build on it more.

Comment: I am afraid if you really wish to go in that direction, you have to ensure that the library builds its JSON objects using your custom class. In other words, you will have to acquire the library's source code and rewrite it yourself.

Comment: Really, that's the only way, you think?